# Possible security risk by sudo on bash exit

Tags: bash, security, sudo, trap

I recently read about using bash's built-in `trap` command to execute a command when bash exits, for example `trap "notify-send test" EXIT` would send a desktop notification as soon as bash terminates. One of the first things, that came to my mind was: Couldn't this be exploited by an attacker? And after a little bit research and trial and error, I found out the following.

The sudo manpage says:

> Security policies may support credential caching to allow the user to
> run sudo again for a period of time without requiring authentication.
> By default, the sudoers policy caches credentials on a per-terminal
> basis for 15 minutes.

I combined these two information, and came up with a command like this: `trap 'printf "" | sudo -S COMMAND &>/dev/null' EXIT`, which automatically executes `COMMAND` when bash exits, if the user used sudo less than 15 minutes ago.

For example. putting the command `trap 'printf "" | sudo -S touch ~/test &>/dev/null' EXIT` in something like ~/.bashrc, would create the file test in the user's home directory, owned by the user `root`, if sudo was used in the bash session not more than 15 minutes ago.

As far as I can see, an attacker could do privilege escalation by inserting this command into a place executed by bash on startup and then just wait, until someone uses sudo in a bash session, and exploit the new privileges, install a backdoor, etc. One thing, he would have to take care of is, that the command delays the termination of bash, so running a long command or an infinite loop would be noticeable by the user, but this can easily be circumvented, by running the command in the background

Is there something I'm missing here? Are there some security restrictions, that I'm not aware of? I tested it on my Ubuntu 22.10 laptop with the Linux 5.19.0-31-generic x86_64 kernel and it worked as expected and created the file. I also tried creating a file in a system directory and even installed a package over apt and it all worked. (A bit of delay while installing the package, but that was expected)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you’re not missing anything as far as the possible exploit. It does work, provided the user has privileges to run arbitrary commands via `sudo`.

You do, however, seem to be missing three other important points here:

- This is not an easy-to-hide attack. Aside from the shutdown timing issue you mention, `sudo` defaults to logging *all* commands executed through it, so there will almost always be a distinct paper trail, and any command output will be visible to the user as well.
- Being able to manipulate the shell startup files of a target user is actually indicative of a pretty deep exploit to begin with. If an attacker has gotten to that point, they *probably* have other ways to get arbitrary code execution as the user in question, and thus likely other options for privilege escalation that are easier to hide than this.
- Credential caching in `sudo` is *optional*. You can turn it off, and most sane, security-conscious, users do so. Ubuntu chooses to have it on by default because they do not see this as a high risk attack vector (because of the above two points) and it makes life easier for lazy users.